# how to retain the value of an uploaded image when i click on the edit post?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, multer

I am using Express, Mongodb for backend and multer library for storing the uploaded images. and ejs as template engine.
I could successfully uploaded the Images, view the uploaded images and delete them. But the problem comes when I tried to edit the post which consist of 3 text fields and an images.
when I click on the edit button i could able to set the value of the input fields of the post which I am editing but it is not same case for the image which i have uploaded.
I need some help.

**edit.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <%- include('../partials/head'); %>
</head>

<body class="container">
    <header>
        <%- include('../partials/header') %>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <form method="post" action="/edit/<%=image._id%>?_method=put" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= image.title %>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">heading</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="heading" value="<%= image.heading %>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">content</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="content" value="<%= image.content %>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">upload</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="myImage" value="<%= image.imageUrl %>">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">update</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <%- include('../partials/footer') %>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**edit routes**

```
app.get('/edit/:id', async(req, res) => {
        const image = await Image.findById(req.params.id);
        if (image)
            res.render('pages/edit', { image: image })
    })
    //edit image 
app.put("/edit/:id", upload.single('myImage'), (req, res, next) => {
        // console.log(req.file);
        const cimage = Image.findById(req.params.id);
        // console.log(cimage.obj);
        cimage.updateOne({
                title: req.body.title,
                content: req.body.content,
                heading: req.body.heading,
                imageUrl: req.file.path
            })
            .then(result => {
                res.redirect('/images')
            })
    })
```

gets redirected to edit page when clicked on the edit button of images.ejs

```
<main>
        <div class="jumbotron container">
            <ul class="row">
                <% images.map((image)=>{%>
                    <li class="col">
                        <p>
                            <%=image.title %>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <%=image.content %>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <%=image.heading %>
                        </p>
                        <img width="600" height="400" src="<%= image.imageUrl %>" alt="">
                        <form method="POST" action="/delete/<%= image._id %>?_method=delete">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">delete</button>
                        </form>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/edit/<%= image._id %>">edit</a>
                    </li>
                    <% })%>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </main>
```